# Переставить первый и третий байт в EAX, а четвертый обнулить

Tags: ассемблер, инспекция-кода

Пример: из `0xAABBCCDD` получить `0x00DDCCBB`

Решил задачу так:

```
MOV  EAX, [EAX]; //инициализация
MOV  ECX, EAX;
SHR  ECX, 16
MOV  DH, $00;
MOV  DL, AL;
SHL  EDX, 16;
MOV  DH, AH;
MOV  DL, CL;
MOV  EAX, EDX;
```

Можно ли улучшить этот код?

ОС: win32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MOV  EAX, [EAX]  ; EAX=0xAABBCCDD
XOR  EBX, EBX    ;                 BL=0x00
XCHG AH,  BL     ; EAX=0xAABB00DD  BL=0xCC
ROR  EAX, 16     ; EAX=0x00DDAABB
MOV  AH,  BL     ; EAX=0x00DDCCBB
```